# Start socket connection after some action vuejs

Tags: sockets, vue.js, vuex

I need to wor with socket io. I make code from official docs

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io'
import socketio from 'socket.io-client'
Vue.use(VueSocketio, socketio('http://b5870557.ngrok.io'), store)
```

Paste this code in my vuex main.js. But it setup connection when i open my first page. But i should to open connection after i download some page or press button. But if i write action

```
 setSocketConnection({commit}, url) {
        Vue.use(VueSocketio, url)
        commit('SOCKET_CONNECT')
    }
```

and call it it needed place

```
created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('setSocketConnection', 'MySocketUrl')
}
```

i cannot get any emits, i mean event listener not working

```
sockets: {
  someEmit: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using vue-router you can do the following:

```
{
   path: '/BB',
   name: 'BB',
   component: BB,
   beforeEnter (to, from, next) {
      if (!Vue.prototype.$socket) { 
         Vue.use(VueSocketio, WS_URL)
      }
      next()
   }
}
```

Source: [How to disabled vue-socket.io in some vue-router component](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/solved-how-to-disabled-vue-socket-io-in-some-vue-router-component/7490)